# mxml null reference

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I have an example custom mxml component CustomRadio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:RadioButton id="radio" />
    <mx:Script>
        public override function set label(value:String):void { 
            this.radio.label = value;
        }
        public override function get label():String {
            return this.radio.label;
        }
    </mx:Script>
</mx:VBox>
```

and an application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"  xmlns:local="*">
    <local:CustomRadio  label="xxx" />
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

And I get Null reference arror in set label saying this.radio is null. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

The RadioButton tag needs to encompass the Script tag. The way you have it now, the script tag is part of the VBox only. Since you are using the 'this' pointer, it's referring to the VBox.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the 'set' function before the value is used(put a trace or similar in there) - is any part of the radio button defined in the 'this' pointer?

Comment: Try this: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Button_with_html_text-14186.html -> looks like you need 'super' instead of 'this'